# How to add User and Admin navigation separate in angular

Tags: angular, navigation

I want to separate admin and user navigation in angular project just like e-commerce website. But children route is not working for dashboard or user. When i click on reports route inside dashboard its give error.
here is my code for this

**app/app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './admin/dashboard.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app/app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Admin/admin.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AdminRoutingModule } from './admin-routing.module';
import { OrderComponent } from './components/order/order.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './components/product/product.component';
import { CustomerComponent } from './components/customer/customer.component';
import { ReportComponent } from './components/report/report.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [OrderComponent, ProductComponent, CustomerComponent, ReportComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AdminRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

**Admin/admin-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ReportComponent } from './components/report/report.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'reports', component: ReportComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

**Admin/dashboard.components.html**

```
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/reports']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" >
      <span data-feather="bar-chart-2"></span>
      Reports
    </a>
  </li>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Admin/components/report/report.components.html**

```
<p>report works!</p>
```

But when i'm trying to access this route its gives error

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'reports'

Comment: I want separate admin panel and separate user profile which navigation is same as home navigation like an e-commerce website, So in angular it is possible or not? I'm confused.

Comment: I think, you can't use same url for different components but I offer you to create a home component and check the role of logged user then according to role active related subcomponent in html.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be clearer if you use children attribute of routes in AppRoutingModule like following:

I used layout component but you can use your modules.

I implemented for one of my projects. you can take a look at  [on my github](https://github.com/abdurrahmanyildiz/AngularWithFakeApi/blob/master/angular/src/app/app-routing.module.ts)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "login", component: AuthlayoutComponent, children: [
      { path: "", component: LoginComponent }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "admin", component: AdminlayoutComponent, children: [
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'report', component: ReportComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "user", component: UserlayoutComponent, children: [
      { path: 'home', component: UserHomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'report', component: UserReportComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**', component: AuthlayoutComponent, children: [
      { path: "", component: LoginComponent }
    ]
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: If I change my routing to this, will it compile separate javascript after compiling? Also what about shared css and shared components?

Comment: Hi, actually it sounds a specific question. The best way to find response try it in your project and modify according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks and it does separate the files.Took me a while to work out. My only problem now is that it doesn't work when I build it into production.

Comment: it is unexpected. Be sure about environment configurations or you can compare final packages